# Squish build for windows server 2008

Tags: python-3.x, squish

Does the squish build used in Windows 7 work for windows server 2008 as well? 
Or should I build squish separately for windows server?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?  In general, and particularly for GUI work, I'd expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Squish binary packages generally work on any supported operating system (they have been compiled for).